# How to create Boolean expression from a namedtuple within a list on Python

Tags: python, list, boolean, namedtuple

```
from collections import namedtuple

Book = namedtuple('Book', 'title author year price')

best = Book('John Dixie',
                'James Pi', 1922, 22.60)

better = Book('Clifford', 
               'Jane Doe', 2005, 20.00)

worst = Book('Nightingale',
                     'Daniel Smith', 1905, 27.90)

booklist = [best, better, worst]
```

With this given information, how do I create a boolean expression that the price of `booklist[0]` is higher than that of `booklist[1]`? I tried comparing `booklist[0[3]]` to `booklist[1[3]]`, but I don't think that's the correct format for comparing a namedtuple within a list. How should I do this?

Comment: It seems that you're have no idea how to even access the data. Why is your question about boolean expressions and comparison? One step at a time.

Comment: I'm asked to compare the prices of best and better using booklist[0] and booklist[1], but the price is within the namedtuple, while the book names are elements within the list named booklist. I have no idea how to say that 22.60 is greater than 20.00 in this format.

In other words, I'm not concerned with the Boolean expression itself. I'm more concerned about how to set up the prices in programming format using the list and namedtuples above.

Comment: So you want to access `....[3]` of that book.

Comment: So, as Karoly says, your question is about accessing data in namedtuples, not about boolean expressions. And to answer that, you should reflect upon the fact that these are called **named**tuples for a good reason.

Comment: " I have no idea how to say that 22.60 is greater than 20.00 in this format." - NO. You have no idea how to get `22.60`. Can we, for the moment, assume that you can compare two numbers?

Comment: I'm sorry if I sound like I have no idea about programming because I really don't. I'm taking an introductory class, so it explains why this question appears basic to you.

And based on what I've learned, best[3] will give me 22.60, but because best is in booklist, I don't know how to get the price with booklist in the equation.

Comment: But the problem is that my professor wants me to use the list booklist = [best, better, worst], and then using the first item of booklist (best) to access the third item of its namedtuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the book (e.g. `booklist[0]`), just write `[3]` after it (no spaces). But prefer to use the name, not an index. It's a *named*tuple.

Whether you have the book in a variable or accessed in a different way (in this case by getting an element from a list) is irrelevant.

Comment: "If you have the book (e.g. booklist[0]), just write [3] after it (no spaces). But prefer to use the name, not an index. It's a namedtuple."

Yup, that's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks, and sorry for the trouble.